# Pass the variable in regular expression within heredoc (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I got the parse error.
I passed the variable in regular expression within heredoc with mysql query expression?

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT
      name, 
      full_code
    FROM M_CATEGORY 
    WHERE full_code REGEXP '^00'.$var.'[0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
    ORDER BY full_code ASC
SQL;
```

Originally the code was

```
$sql = "
SELECT
  name, 
  full_code
FROM M_CATEGORY 
WHERE full_code REGEXP '^00".$var."[0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
ORDER BY full_code ASC";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT
      name,
      full_code
    FROM M_CATEGORY
    WHERE full_code REGEXP '^00{$var}[0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
    ORDER BY full_code ASC
SQL;
```

Please, read about heredoc: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc